# Is there a .Net equivalent of Apache CXF Framework?

Tags: .net, frameworks

Here is the wiki for those who want to know about Apache CXF.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_CXF

I am looking for something similar or .Net ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a lot like [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx). What's the use case?

Comment: auto generate REST services based on your object model.

Comment: Totally missed that in all of the marketing speak at the Fuse web site.  Note that FUSE does offer a Windows version, though not .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite from your object model, but [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) will "generate" a REST service that exposes your data from a database.